# Increasing the volume of media player while playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, volume

i want to make a special alarm app and the user should have the possibility to be woken up with music getting louder e.g. for 60 seconds.
I could not find a way to do this, that's why I need your help.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad English

```
final AudioManager am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    oldvolume=am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100,0);
    if (increase<=0)  mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume,volume);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    if (increase>0){
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
        final double hohe=volume/increase;
        new CountDownTimer((increase*1000),1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.setVolume((float) hohe*millisUntilFinished,(float) hohe*(increase*1000-millisUntilFinished));
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.setVolume( volume,volume);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }.start();
```

That's what i got until now.
increase= increasing time in seconds
volume= max volume alarm should have

Comment: I tried to stop the player increase volume and restart it again but that didn't work and also only increasing the volume didn't work

Comment: Why do you need it? It doesn't work xD

Comment: Okay, I added it xD

Answer (score 0):

Solution, works for me is:

```
   private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mVolumeRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null&&currentvolume<endvolume) {
            currentvolume += volumeincrease;
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(currentvolume/100f, currentvolume/100f);
            Toast.makeText(AlertActivity.this,String.valueOf(currentvolume),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mHandler.postDelayed(mVolumeRunnable, 1000);
        }
        else mHandler.removeCallbacks(mVolumeRunnable);
    }
};
```